# Como separar valores de un array en JS y pasarlo a plantilla PUG

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pug

tengo una formulario en pug lo que quiero que muestre es una variable que me trae a los usuarios asignados , logro obtener los campos pero me vienen todos juntos en un texto completo asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Extraigo mis datos de este JS

**JS**

ajaxDinamicoForm("permisos/obtenerUsuarioXPerfil", formData, function(data) {
                resultados = data.resultados;

```
            var val = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < data.resultados.length; i++) {
                val.push(resultados[i].idUsuario);
            }


            // DOC
            $("#nUsuarios").html(val);
        });

    });
```

**PLANTILLA PUG**

```
  .modal-body
                        .row.no-gutters 

                            .col-6.p-5
                                legend.no-border.f-w-600.f-s-10.text-inverse.text-center.m-t-10 USUARIOS ASOCIADOS

                                   li.text-capitalize#nUsuarios(style = "color:#FF0000")  

                            .col-12.p-5(align="center") ¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?
```

Lo que quiero es que estos datos se me muestren listado en la platilla pug

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente seria adecuado ver como esta saliendo la data que traes mediante el ajax,  recuerda que el pug se encarga de renderizar la vista por ende el resultado final es html y si usas jquery puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 ajaxDinamicoForm("permisos/obtenerUsuarioXPerfil", formData, function(data) { resultados = data.resultados;

        var a=0;
        var htmls='<ul style= "padding: 0px;">';

        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            htmls+=`<li style="color:#FF0000;">`+value.idUsuario+` </li>`;
          });

          htmls+='</ul>';
          $('#n_Usuarios').html(htmls);
    });

});
```

Nunca e utilizado pug pero creo que el código te quedaría así

```
    .row.no-gutters
  .col-6.p-5
    legend.no-border.f-w-600.f-s-10.text-inverse.text-center.m-t-10
      | USUARIOS ASOCIADOS
      ul#nUsuarios
  .col-12.p-5(align='center') &iquest;Esta seguro que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?
```

Cada elemento li caerá dentro del ul mediante el .html que usas indicándole el id de ese elemento.

Saludos